# Why const char* static field has to be constexpr to initialize it inside class?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-initialization, in-class-initialization

I have the following piece of code:

```
struct st
{
  static constexpr const int x = 2;
  static constexpr int x2 = 2;
  static const int x3 = 2;
  static const char* str = "BLAH"; // ERROR
};
```

marked line gives me the following error:

> error: ‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialization of static data
>   member ‘const char* st::str’ of non-integral type [-fpermissive]

When I add `constexpr` to it, it's all dandy.

```
struct st
{
  // ...
  static constexpr const char* str = "BLAH"; // OK
};
```

Why is it like this? Since initialization of non plain types (e.g. `std::string` or user defined types) are not allowed in class body why `const char*` is but only with `constexpr`?